# Zero ATK Fighting zero ATK

Tags: yu-gi-oh

What happens if a 0 ATK monster attacks another 0 ATK monster?

I would say that since monsters do not have any attack, they can't do any damage, so nothing happens. On the other hand there is this rule stating that if a monster attacks an equal ATK monster, both monsters are destroyed during the fight.

I read a little bit of everything on the internet, what do you think about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the rules nothing happens:

> **0 ATK monsters**
>
> Monsters with 0 ATK cannot destroy anything by battle. If two Attack Position monsters with 0 ATK battle each other, neither monster is destroyed.

End of page 46 (or PDF page 50) here: https://img.yugioh-card.com/uk/rulebook/Rulebook_v9_en.pdf